# toString method of Binary Tree using java

Tags: javascript, java, binary-tree

Expected `(A (D () ()) (B (C () ()) ()))`

Got `A(D() ()) (B(C() ()) ())`

I lost the first and last bracket.

```
private String toString(BinaryNode curr) {

    String str = "";
    if(curr == null) {
        return str;
    } else{
    str += curr.value;
    str += "(" + toString(curr.left) + ") (" + toString(curr.right) + ")";
    }

    return str;
}
```

And if I changed my code, I got `(A((D() ())) ((B((C() ())) ())))`

```
private String toString(BinaryNode curr) {

    String str = "";
    if(curr == null) {
        return str;
    } else{
    str += curr.value;
    str += "(" + toString(curr.left) + ") (" + toString(curr.right) + ")";
    }

    return "(" + str + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide which part of the code is responsible for surrounding by parenthesis. The ones at the return seems to do the job:

```
private String toString(BinaryNode curr) {

    String str = "";
    if(curr == null) {
        return str;
    } else{
        str += curr.value+" ";
        str += toString(curr.left) + toString(curr.right);
    }

return "(" + str + ")";
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much! I should put the brackets outside the recursion.